# Jquery slidedown to show on top of other content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have on piece of content and I just want to display other piece of code on top of it, using Jquery slidedown as an overlay. I already added z-index properties but I can't make it work.

I want the div with class "selection_nip" to appear as an overlay on top of class ""

Sorry for any bad formatting.

HTML code

```
    <div id="ask_question_post_envelop" class="bottom_border_radius" style="position:relative; z-index:10;">

                <div class="selection_nip" style="display:none; position:relative; z-index:1000;"></div>
                    <span id="arrow-dashboard" class="arrow-dashboard"></span>
                    <div id="avatar-wraper" class="avatar-wraper">
                        <a href="#" class="post-avatar" id="" ><img id="avatar-img" src="<?php echo $user_data['photo'];?>" border="0" alt=""></a>
                    </div>  

                    <div id="form_wrapper_question" class="form_wrapper_question" >
                        <!--    ONDE ENTRAM TODAS AS FORMS         -->  
                </div>



                <div id="" class="question-page-form_wrapper" name="profile_identifier" style="position:relative; z-index:10;">
                    <div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
                        <input id="profile_id" type="text" name="profile_id" value="<?php echo $profile_data['user_id']; ?>"/>
                    </div>
               </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to position div "`selection_nip`" with position `absolute`.

```
#selection_nip {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

It will position on top of div `#ask_question_post_envelop` content (first parent with position relative).

You will get something like that:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz47j/1/)